# На какой срок лучше покупать домен

Tags: домен

Посоветуйте пожалуйста, на какой срок сразу лучше покупать домен? Ну чтобы иметь больший траст поисковиков к этому домену и т.д.

Comment: "Больший траст" это?

Comment: На один, итить его, год.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день. Вы можете регистрировать домен и на минимальный период (1 год), а если хотите индексировать сайт или нужно будет подтверждение от поисковиков, что это Ваш домен, то там есть соответствующая процедура, о которой техподдержка поисковиков Вам скажет. Обычно, это либо добавить файл в корень Вашего сайта либо добавить TXT-запись в домен (содержимое и все необходимое Вам скажут представители компании)

Период регистрации домена - это далеко не самый важный пункт